# Output impedance of small-signal model

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, small-signal

[image]

When I calculate the output impedance (Rout) of this small signal model, do I have to short circuit between 2 ends of the blue wire or black wire?

Comment: When finding Rout you need to set Vin to 0V. So you simply short-circuit the input voltage source.

Answer (score 2):

For this circuit, it doesn't matter - no matter whether you short blue or black and no matter what test voltage/current you apply on the output side of the small-signal model, vpi is zero. You should obtain the same output impedance in both cases.

In cases where the two sides are linked more closely (e.g. there is a feedback effect or resistance bridging the input and output sides), it *does* sometimes matter. For those cases I would short at the blue line (null the voltage source but keep its source impedance). This ensures that the calculated output impedance is based on how the amplifier is actually operated when connected to its source.

Comment: Oh, I think it matters in this Circuit. If Rs = 0, easily say that vbe = 0 (ib = 0). But when Rs are available, vbe and ib are not zero.

Comment: KVL: 0 = iRs*Rs + Vbe (Vpi).

Comment: @Southgoodman for small signal it does not matter in this circuit. No matter what you do on the output side, you can't influence Vbe because no current can cross from right to left. And because Vs was replaced by a short circuit, small signal Vbe is 0 in both cases, and is is 0 as well

Answer (score 0):

is RL = Rout ? If yes, why would you short circuit it at the blue line? Impedance is the effective resistance of a circuit.

Comment: I think Rout absolutely not the same as RL (Rload), when we calculate Rout, there is no Rload.

Comment: @Southgoodman Yes, the output impedance (Rout) is irrelevant to the load. And if the Rs represents the internal resistance of your power supply, then short circuit between 2 ends of the black wire when calculating the Rout.

Comment: Yes, Rs is the internal resistance of the power supply, but even if it is internal resistance, when we modified Vs -> Vs = 0V, internal resistance is still here (I think we don't take Vs out of the circuit when calculating Rout, just Vs = 0V is the same with short circuit blue wire)

Comment: Oh no, My bad. I'm understanding. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Southgoodman Sorry, I make a mistake. I came back to check out my textbook and found we should keep the internal resistance when calculating the Rout. You can take the common collector amplifier circuit as a example because the Rout of common collector amplifier circuit is relevant to the Rs.

Comment: oh :D:D. thanks, mate.

Comment: What is the name of this book? Can you give me the name and the page number of this example (CC with Rout have Rs in equations). I ask for this example because my teacher also gives an example of CC circuit with Rs of power supply but he short circuit the black line when considering small-signal model. So confused.

Comment: @Southgoodman ok. For your convenience, I will directly post it as an answer. And maybe you should @ to remind me, because if you don't do that, only Luis (answerer) will get the response.

Answer (score 0):

We should keep the internal resistance \$Rs\$ of power supply when calculating the Rout. Although in this circuit, it doesn't matter. But in some cases, the \$Rout\$ is relevant to the \$Rs\$. Here is a example(from *模拟电子技术基础（第四版）童诗白* Tsinghua University P104).
(a) is a common collector amplifier circuit using Darlington. (c) is the small signal circuit of it.
[image]
The output impedence is as follows:
[image]

Comment: The policy for answers on this site is that you need to provide proper citations or links to the original source of graphics that you copy. Could you add those, please?